# How to generate an activeadmin resource in a custom directory instead of admin directory?

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

After making changes in initializers/active_admin to work with two namespaces , I m facing to the problem of generating new resources in my custom directory, i want to separate the user's resources with the admin resources.
Someone can help?

I configured the way to use more than one namespaces in my active_admin project and I was expecting to find the way to generate some resources in admin folder and some other in my custom folder 'companies'

thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `cancancan` gem? It should help you to programmatically control access to sections in your code, based on permissions

Answer (score 1):

Your `initializers/active_admin.rb` should contain `config.load_paths += [...]` where you can enumerate multiple directories containing resource registration files.